# after dbus resart, there is two dbus deamon, and systemd is timeout

Tags: ubuntu, dbus

my machine:

```
root@gpuworker-gv100:~# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: gpuworker-gv100
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Machine ID: 2cfbb46ca0aa4ee4a74bc67a9f526884
           Boot ID: 881832233ab64f80bc56e6c6ac804350
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-81-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

my system:

```
root@gpuworker-gv100:~# uname -r
5.4.0-81-generic
root@gpuworker-gv100:~# uname 
Linux
```

my step:

```
systemctl restart dbus.service
```

result:

```
root@gpuworker-gv100:~# ps -ef |grep dbus
message+  1629     1  0 15:42 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
message+ 20527     1  0 15:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
root     54073  8507  0 16:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dbus
```

logs:

```
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[1629]: [system] Activating systemd to hand-off: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostn>
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 systemd[1]: dbus.service: Found left-over process 1629 (dbus-daemon) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[20527]: dbus[20527]: Unknown username "whoopsie" in message bus configuration file
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[1629]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[20527]: dbus[20527]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[20527]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[1629]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Aug 25 15:47:42 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[1629]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug 25 15:47:47 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[20527]: [system] Activating systemd to hand-off: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.host>
Aug 25 15:48:12 gpuworker-gv100 dbus-daemon[20527]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

when execute command:

```
root@gpuworker-gv100:~# hostnamectl
Failed to query system properties: Connection timed out
```

when i kill -9 20527

```
root@gpuworker-gv100:~# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: gpuworker-gv100
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Machine ID: 2cfbb46ca0aa4ee4a74bc67a9f526884
           Boot ID: 881832233ab64f80bc56e6c6ac804350
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-81-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

but there is dbus-deamon process start auto.
after few second, still have two dbus-deamon. and hostnamectl is start timeout.
please help me !!!

I want have one dbus-deamon process and hostnamectl is normal.